# Global array heap memory allocation in an online judge platform

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

here is a simplest program:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
char c[1000 * 1000 * 100]; 
int main() { 
     int a, b; 
     while (cin >> a >> b) { 
         cout << a+b << endl; 
     } 
     return 0; 
}
```

this is a very simple a+b problem, almost every online judge use it as the first problem.

it declare a global char array which occupy 100MB memory space. and it will exceed the momory limit of most online judge platform.

but, when i use this code to submmit to different oj platform, the result is different.
for example, the poj and hduoj is "accepted", but zoj will be "memory limit".

so I guess when the program runs, the 100MB memory will not be allocted immediately, until you use memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));

but why some platform alloted heap memory immediately?
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is not allocated on the heap. It is stored in the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). The data segment is reserved when the process is loaded.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. but i wonder if it is allocted immediately?